# Parallel Computation: Kill kernels which have completed the jobs while others keep running

Tags: parallelization, kernel, command-line, kernel-startup

I launch 20 parallel kernels in the background using

`nohup math -run "<<file.m" &> file.out`

The nature of computation is integration over various parameters, whose values are picked from random distributions. Hence, many kernels finish their jobs much before the rest but remain in sleeping mode and are not killed until the whole bunch of 20 computations is finished.

Is there a way to kill the kernels after they finish their job, so that I can launch more kernels? I need to do atleast 500 such computations and waiting for a bunch of 20 to finish is taking a lot of time.

Comment: I think you're going about this the wrong way. Why don't you do all the calculations in a single session instead of running many independent kernel processes? Use a single master kernel, and feed jobs to the subkernels continuously. If some subkernels finish much later than others, you should probably be using `Method -> "FinestGrained"` in the parallelization functions.

Comment: Actually integration limits are decided by some parameters. So some integration limits might be 10 to 1500 while some might just be 10 to 100. The integrands are also highly oscillatory. So, it is not so much of a parallelization problem I think.

Can you tell me how to feed jobs to the subkernels?

Comment: What I meant is that you should not launch more main kernels. Do everything in one script.